# Problems running query with natural join

Tags: php, mysql

Am I doing this natural join correctly? I get NULL every time I run the Query

```
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost:3307","root","");

    mysqli_select_db($con, 'project');

    // Check connection
    if (!$con){
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    };

    mysqli_query ($con,"set character_set_results='utf8'");
$inv_id= "Please enter an invoice ID";
$cus_name = "";
$cus_phone = "";
$inv_total = "" ;
$ship_date = "";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $inv_id = $_POST['inv_id'];
    //echo $inv_id;
    $sql = 'SELECT inv_total, ship_date, cus_name, cus_phone
            from invoiceheader natural join shipment natural join customer
            where inv_id = \'' . $inv_id . '\' '; 
            //echo $sql;

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        if(!$result)
           {
                echo "SQL Select query failed!";
        } 
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();  
        //var_dump($row);   
        $cus_name = $row["cus_name"];
        $cus_phone = $row["cus_phone"];
        $inv_total = $row["inv_total"];
        $ship_date = $row["ship_date"];
}

?>
```

I get null on var_dump and empty set on sql command line but no errors.

```html
mysql> select * from invoiceheader;
+--------+---------------------+--------+-----------+---------------------+
| inv_id | inv_date            | cus_id | inv_total | last_modified_date  |
+--------+---------------------+--------+-----------+---------------------+
| 111111 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |      1 |        53 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |
| 111112 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |      2 |      41.5 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |
| 111113 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |      3 |        26 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |
| 111114 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |      4 |        51 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |
| 111115 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |      5 |     38.75 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |
| 111116 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |      6 |        55 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |
| 111117 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |      7 |     41.25 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |
| 111118 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |      8 |     71.25 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |
| 111119 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |      9 |     28.25 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |
| 111120 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |     10 |     69.25 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |
| 111121 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |      6 |      65.5 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |
| 111122 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |      3 |        58 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |
+--------+---------------------+--------+-----------+---------------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from customer;
+--------+--------------------+------------+-----------------+--------------------+---------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| cus_id | cus_name           | cus_phone  | customer_email  | street             | city          | state | zip   | lastOrderDate | creation_date       | last_modified_date  |
+--------+--------------------+------------+-----------------+--------------------+---------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|      1 | John Murray        | 1111111111 | cus1@email.com  | 123 first street   | Egan          | MN    | 51224 | 2017-01-10    | 2017-04-05 19:16:07 | 2017-04-05 19:16:07 |
|      2 | Rachael Smith      | 2222222222 | cus2@email.com  | 123 second street  | Minnetonka    | MN    | 55266 | 2017-01-10    | 2016-12-30 23:35:22 | 2016-12-30 23:35:22 |
|      3 | Addison Brown      | 3333333333 | cus3@email.com  | 123 third street   | Bloominton    | MN    | 55757 | 2017-01-10    | 2016-12-30 23:35:22 | 2016-12-30 23:35:22 |
|      4 | Mike Lewis         | 4444444444 | cus4@email.com  | 123 fourth street  | Egan          | MN    | 51224 | 2017-01-10    | 2017-04-05 19:16:08 | 2017-04-05 19:16:08 |
|      5 | Matt Collins       | 5555555555 | cus5@email.com  | 123 fifth street   | New Hope      | MN    | 55336 | 2017-01-10    | 2016-12-30 23:35:22 | 2016-12-30 23:35:22 |
|      6 | Jonathan Elliot    | 6666666666 | cus6@email.com  | 123 sixth street   | Watertown     | MN    | 50221 | 2017-01-10    | 2016-12-30 23:35:22 | 2016-12-30 23:35:22 |
|      7 | Jessica Stratmeyer | 7777777777 | cus7@email.com  | 123 seventh street | Egan          | MN    | 51224 | 2017-01-10    | 2016-12-30 23:35:22 | 2016-12-30 23:35:22 |
|      8 | David Wilson       | 8888888888 | cus8@email.com  | 123 eighth street  | Minneapolis   | MN    | 55346 | 2017-01-10    | 2016-12-30 23:35:22 | 2016-12-30 23:35:22 |
|      9 | Macklin Johnson    | 9999999999 | cus9@email.com  | 123 ninth street   | St louis park | MN    | 55348 | 2017-01-10    | 2016-12-30 23:35:22 | 2016-12-30 23:35:22 |
|     10 | Tony Bui           | 1231231230 | cus10@email.com | 123 tenth street   | Chanhassen    | MN    | 55341 | 2017-01-10    | 2016-12-30 23:35:22 | 2016-12-30 23:35:22 |
+--------+--------------------+------------+-----------------+--------------------+---------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from shipment;
+---------+--------+--------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| ship_id | inv_id | cus_id | ship_date  | creation_date       | last_modified_date  |
+---------+--------+--------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|      21 | 111111 |      1 | 2016-12-01 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |
|      22 | 111112 |      2 | 2016-12-03 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |
|      23 | 111113 |      3 | 2016-12-01 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |
|      24 | 111114 |      4 | 2016-12-05 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |
|      25 | 111115 |      5 | 2016-12-01 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |
|      26 | 111116 |      6 | 2016-12-02 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |
|      27 | 111117 |      7 | 2016-12-01 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |
|      28 | 111118 |      8 | 2016-12-03 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |
|      29 | 111119 |      9 | 2016-12-05 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |
|      30 | 111120 |     10 | 2016-12-02 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |
|      31 | 111121 |      6 | 2016-12-04 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |
|      32 | 111122 |      3 | 2016-12-01 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 | 2016-11-30 23:35:22 |
+---------+--------+--------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT cus_name, cus_phone, inv_id, inv_total, ship_date
    ->             from customer natural join shipment natural join invoiceheader
    ->             where inv_id =111111;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

I have attached my db schema if it helps. I tried removing the run_sql function nut still no luck. When I do only one natural join it seems to work.

Comment: What are the common columns taking part in that natural join?

Comment: What is `run_sql`? Also you should be binding your values to the query, not including them directly in the query because that leaves you open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: What is `run_sql`? What database adapter are you using? This code looks vaguely like `mysqli` at its core.

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in your query.

Comment: run_sql is a function I have defined in the db_config file. It's basically doing $result = $db->query($sql_script); inside the function.  @mike

Comment: The commom columns between invoiceheader and shipment is inv_id, shipment and customer is customer_id. @Hmmm

Comment: `SELECT inv_total, ship_date, cus_name, cus_phone from invoiceheader natural join shipment natural join customer where inv_id = '111111'` `NULL` is what I'm getting.     `mysql> SELECT inv_id, inv_total,cus_name, cus_phone
    ->             from invoiceheader natural join customer
    ->             where inv_id =111111;
Empty set (0.00 sec)`

Comment: Working fine for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15083a/3/0 I suggest getting rid of the `run_sql` and just run the query directly, for starters. You aren't saving yourself any typing there.

Comment: I added my db schema if it helps @miken32. I tried removing `run_sql` but still no luck.

Comment: As I demonstrated, the query is fine. Your DB connection is not working or there's some other problem.

Comment: Thanks @miken32. Appreciate the help.

Comment: While perfectly correct, I would discourage the use of natural joins. As your schema and queries become more complex, they're sure to fail or, worse, produce misleading results.

Comment: Performing a full join like `... FROM invoiceheader JOIN shipment ON invoiceheader.inv_id = shipment.inv_id JOIN shipment.cus_id=customer.cus_id` should work just fine. I strongly prefer these explicit joins (where the referred columns are given by the programmer) because they provide much more information.

Comment: thanks @LennartKloppenburg. I will give that a try. But the issue I am having is the query is returning NULL for me.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment:

1. Separate database logic from application logic by isolating the query that is executed: Print it in your application or recreate it yourself.
2. Run the query in a MySQL console or via phpMyAdmin or whatever software you use for this.

What does it return? If the query does not return anything, make sure the fields that are supposed to join the tables (`cus_id`, `inv_id`) are **identical** across the tables in which they appear. I.e., `inv_id` has to have the same daratype in `invoiceheader` and `shipment`. If the datatypes aren't identical, then they can't be joined either.

If this is all in order, rebuild your query incrementally. Start off with a simple `SELECT ... FROM ...` and then attach a `JOIN` to that, and then the other, all the while making sure the problem does not occur there.

Finally, the problem could be within your `WHERE` clause as well. Make sure the datatype of this column matches the way you're querying for it. (Note: Building your queries like this is prone to error, it's better to prepare them using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php))

This is a bit generic, but it's difficult to be specific when I don't know your database schema.